# Django - Updating DateField when Foreign table get modified

Tags: python, django

I have the following issue, here is my (simplified) model:

```
Mother(models.Model):
    child                       = models.ForeignKey("Child")
    last_modification           = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
    name                        = models.CharField()  

Child(models.Model):
    name                        = models.CharField()
```

I would like the last_modification field of the Mother to be updated when the Child.name get modified.

I saw there was an "on_delete" method available for the Mother class, but is there some kind of "on_modified" ?

I must be able to update the date manually by overriding the Child save() method but it seems ugly. It seems to be an honest feature, so there is maybe already something to do that directly ?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save ?

Comment: better than overriding the save() method but I still need to do the update of the date manually...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it by adding a "last_modification" field to the Child class + a get_last_modification() on the Mother class which returns the most recent of the 2 dates. but I'm not very happy with my solution :-)